# Небо с овчинку

Tags: фразеология

Давно интересует это выражение. Понятно, что означает оно "мало не покажется", то есть, что будет плохо. Но почему именно такое выражение? Честно говоря, я плохо представляю себе, как может небо показаться маленьким, что бы не случилось.
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

"- Что, ваше благородие? - сказал он мне.- Струсил ты, признайся, когда мои молодцы накинули тебе веревку на шею? Я чаю, небо с овчинку показалось?"
А.С. Пушкин «Капитанская дочка»

Многие фразеологизмы связаны с трудовой деятельностью:  от плотников ведет свое начало фразеологизм «топорная работа», от скорняков -  «небо с овчинку показалось, овчинка выделки не стоит».

Как описать сильное потрясение, которое испытывает человек? Страх  сжимает всё его существо,  он весь поглощен страхом или болью, так что окружающий мир перестает  для него существовать, и даже огромное небо уменьшается до размеров овечьей шкурки.

Кстати, на способности человека направлять свое сознание в конкретную область  тела, стягивать его в точечную область основаны многие духовные и целительные практики.